# Can't pass data via AJAX to Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Пытаюсь передать переменные через Ajax в Laravel 5.1

Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: "post",
    url: '/orders/api/store',
    data: {
        _method: 'post',
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
        message: '123',
        id: 1,
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::post('/orders/api/store', 'OrdersController@apiStore');
```

И сама функция обрабочтик:

```
public function apiStore(Request $request) {

    $response = [
        'request' => request('message'),
        'message' => 'works',
        'status' => '200'
    ];

    return response()->json($response);

}
```

Результат выполнения следующий:

```
{request: null, message: "works", status: "200"}
```

При попытке считать переменную message возвращается null

Comment: плиз транслейт то рашн

Comment: can you show dd($request->all()); from your function?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Перевел

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам стоит проверять, как изменяется request на протяжении всего цикла запроса. Если вы его отправляете, то он однозначно приходит, но где-то, видимо, подвергается мутаторам. Проверяйте мидлвары, объект Request и попробуйте вывести в лог просмотр $request->message, чтобы посмотреть, что внутри

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была решена спустя 2 дня: помогло создание переменной data типа Object, заполнение ее полей нужными данными, и передача на бекенд с помочью JSON.stringify(data)

```
function submitOrder() {
console.log(JSON.stringify(order.positions));
console.log('SENDING ORDER ',order.positions, ' to the database');

var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
var data = {};
data.order = order.positions;
data._method = 'POST';
data._token = CSRF_TOKEN;
$.ajax({
    //FIXME No response
    // headers: {
    //     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    // },
    type: "POST",
    url: '/orders/api/store/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Это определённо не выход, а костыль. Бороться надо с причиной, а вы боретесь с последствием. Вам годный совет дали под постом.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $response = [
    'request' => request('message'),
    'message' => 'works',
    'status' => '200'
];
```

Ошибка в переменной (не обозначили её) `$request('message')`

A лучше `$request->message`

Comment: Нет, ошибки никакой нет. `request()` - стандартный хелпер в laravel, позволяющий получить данные по ключу через передачу параметра.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, смысл внедрять $request и использовать хелпер тогда?

Comment: @Алексей да, без разницы как делать: или через хелпер, или через переменную. Результат один и тот же, null